# Timedeltas between lines for loyalty calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I was able to make such table of orders with help of pandas:
[image]

```
   identifier  gender       Date category
0           1  female 2016-11-11     Baby
1           1  female 2017-02-01     Baby
2           2  female 2016-12-19    Shave
3           2  female 2016-12-27    Shave
4           3  female 2016-11-11     Baby
5           3  female 2016-11-22     Baby
6           4    male 2016-11-11    Shave
7           4    male 2017-01-01    Shave
```

I need result as number of orders first and second orders by days:

```
first order:
11.11.2016 3
19.12.2016 1

second orders:
22.11.2016 1
21.12.2016 1
01.01.2017 1
02.01.2017 1

third orders:
```

And also i need calculate average time between orders (be person)

```
average time between orders = ...
```

And assess cross category loyalty of clients. I feel that these taska looks similar

```
 Loyalty cross categories:
    first order:
    Baby  2
    second order:
    Baby - 2
    third order:


    first order:
    Shave  2
    second order:
    Shave - 2
    third order:
```

Is it possible to do such analysis with pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Given this dataframe

```
   identifier  gender       Date category
0           1  female 2016-11-11     Baby
1           1  female 2017-02-01     Baby
2           2  female 2016-12-19    Shave
3           2  female 2016-12-27    Shave
4           3  female 2016-11-11     Baby
5           3  female 2016-11-22     Baby
6           4    male 2016-11-11    Shave
7           4    male 2017-01-01    Shave
```

You can start by using the series shift in a group function

```
df_groups = df.groupby('identifier')
df['last_order'] = df_groups.Date.shift(1)
```

Then you can get the time between orders

```
df['Time_between_orders'] = df['last_order'] - df['Date']
```

And then you can get the average time between orders per user like this:

```
df_groups = df.groupby('identifier')
df_groups['Time_between_orders'].apply(lambda x: x.sum() / x.notnull().sum()).apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

Will give:

```
identifier
1          -82
2           -8
3          -11
4          -51
```

If you want this across categories, just add category to all the group statements. `df.groupby('identifier')` becomes `df.groupby(['identifier', 'category'])`